# Probability related to record index that cross zeros in $[0, 1, \cdots, N]^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

This question is inspired by this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02095). For those who are interested in more details and applications about record index and record values, you can find them in the paper.

Let $X=\{0, 1, 2, \cdots, N\}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ ($N>1$) and $p$ be a non-uniform distribution on $X$ such that for each $0\leq i \leq N$, $p(i)=\lambda_i\in(0, 1)$. Then consider the probability space $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by finite cylinder sets and the product probability measure $\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb{N}}p$. For my convenience given any $i, j\in\mathbb{N}$ I use $[i, j]$ to denote the set $\{i, i+1, \cdots, j\}$ if $i\leq j$; when $i>j$, $[i, j] = \emptyset$. Fix $n\in X\backslash \{0\}$ and $\{s_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ an increasing finite subsequence of $X\backslash\{0\}$. Then define the following new notation:

> Given $x = (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$, whenever there exists an increasing finite set $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{j_1} = s_1, x_{j_2} = s_2, \cdots, x_{j_n} = s_n$, we say $(s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} \subseteq x$. In this case we call $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ the **record index** of $x$. When $(s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} \subseteq x$, we further say **$x$ contains zeros** if there exists $1\leq i < n$ and $l\in \{x_{j_i+1}, x_{j_i+2}, \cdots, x_{j_{i+1}-1}\}$ such that $x_l=0$. When $(n_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq x$ and $x$ contains zeros, we use $o(x)$ to denote the index $l$ such that $x_l=0$.

Let $S$ denote the set of all $x\in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(s_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq x$ and $x$ contains zeros. Next define:

> Suppose $x\in S$. Let $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ be the record index of $x$. In this case we say $\{j_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ **cross the zeros of $x$** if given any $l\in o(x)$, if $l\in [j_i+1, \cdots, j_{i+1}-1]$ for some $1\leq i < n$, then $$\large \max\{ x_{j_i+1}, x_{j_i+2}, \cdots, x_{l-1}\}\leq s_i$$

Now what is the measure of the set $\big\{ x\in S: \text{the record index of }\, x\, \text{ cross zeros of  }\, x\big\}$?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $o(x)$.  What if there are multiple indices $i$ such that $x_i=0$?  Similarly, there might be multiple valid record indices, so the phrase "the record index" is misleading -- perhaps you mean "a record index".  I don't see where you ever use the notation $[i,j]$.  What is $m_k$?  Do you mean $j_{i+1}$?

Comment: You ask here two questions (one about $S$, one about its subset).  Please ask only one question per post.  If you have two questions, you can ask them separately with the 'Ask Question' button.

Comment: That would fine. All I want is that there exists $l \in [j_i+1, \cdots, j_{i+1}-1]$ such that $x_l=0$.

Comment: Please don't add clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it is clear for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I hope now the question is more clear.

Comment: Nitpick: It still contains the errors I've pointed out before: in the definition of $o(x)$, you write "denote the index" when there might be multiple such indices, so "the index" is not well-defined; and same for "the record index".  Perhaps you mean "an index" and "a record index".  It is not clear what set you want the measure of.  Do you want to know about $x$ for which there exists a record index that crosses zeros of $x$?

Comment: What does "given any $l \in (x)$" mean?  Is that a "for all $l$" or "there exists $l$"?

Comment: This is a very specific question. What is the motivation for this question?  Why will it be of interest to other readers in the future?  An important part of our mission here is to build an archive of knowledge in the form of questions & answers that will likely be useful to others in the future.  It might help if you could motivate why this will ever be relevant to anyone other than you.